# Hibernate OneToMany List - Check to see if any new entities have been added

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading

I have a Hibernate entity that has a OneToMany relationship (FetchType.LAZY) with another entity using a List.  I have some logic that I would like to run iff a new entity has been added to the list, but I do not want to load up any of the existing entities in the list from the database.

I gather from the [Advanced FAQ](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-AdvancedProblems#jive_content_id_Why_does_Hibernate_always_initialize_a_collection_when_I_only_want_to_add_or_remove_an_element) that I can add a new entry to the list without causing Hibernate to initialize the list (so far so good).  However, after I have the entity added to the list, I cannot figure out how to go back and check to see if it is in there.

Calling isEmpty() and size() both initialize the list and so are no good. For the record, when I say "initialized" I mean the read action that Hibernate takes to load records from the database.  If a list is not initialized, Hibernate.isInitialized(List) should return false.

If anyone has any suggestions regarding this, I would very much appreciate them.  Thank you!